# PHP : how to get original value of number after being scaled (for zoom logic)

Tags: php, zooming

currently i am making some "zoom in / zoom out" logic in php,
and now i have some problem with scaling value and reverting it back to original value in php (if applicable to js it would be awesome).

here is the codes

```
$scale          = 1;
$currentScale   = 1;
$position       = 50;
$step           = 5; // or 10

for($index = 1; $index <= $step; $index++){
    echo('-----------------------------------------------------<br>');

    $currentScale       = $scale / $index;
    $position           = $position * $currentScale;
    $originalPosition   = (($scale / $currentScale) * $position) * (($scale / $currentScale) / $scale);

    echo('current scale : ' . $currentScale . '<br>');
    echo('current position : ' . $position . '<br>');
    echo('original position : ' . $originalPosition . '<br>');
}
```

the goal is to make the $originalPosition value same as the first $position value (on every scale), i have tried many formula but no luck, hope you guys can help.

thanks in advance.

## rule $originalPosition not stored before loop

Comment: I'm probably missing something, but why not just set `$originalPosition` to `$position` before the loop?

Comment: Could it really be that simple :) :)

Comment: no, it not that simple, the goal is to "revert" the looped $position (after being scaled) to its initial value

Answer (score 0):

ok, i think i found out the solution, i'll leave this code here in case somebody facing same problem

```
    $scale          = 1;
    $currentScale   = 1;
    $position       = 80; // change it to any value
    $step           = 5;

    echo('original position : ' . $position . '<br>');

    for($i = $step; $i >= 1; $i--){
        echo('-----------------------------------------------------<br>');

        $currentScale       = ($scale / $step) * $i;
        $position           = $position * $currentScale;
        $originalPosition   = $position;

        $maxLoop = $step - $i;

        if($maxLoop){
            for($j = $maxLoop; $j >= 0 ; $j--){
                $tempScale          = $scale - (($scale / $step) * $j);
                $originalPosition   = $originalPosition / $tempScale;
            }
        }

        echo('max rescale loop : ' . $maxLoop . '<br>');
        echo('current scale : ' . $currentScale . ' ( ' . $currentScale * 100 . '% )<br>');
        echo('current position : ' . $position . '<br>');
        echo('original position : ' . $originalPosition . '<br>');
    }
    exit;
```

here is the result, the original position stays the same as initial value
[image]